# Google Maps Autocomplete Within a City

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places

I am in a situation which i need to limit Google Maps Autocomplete to a specific city results.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var autocomplete =
      new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          document.getElementById('addr'));

  autocomplete.setTypes(['address']);
  autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country':'us'});

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',
        function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            $('#name').text(place.formatted_address);
            $('#lat').text(place.geometry.location.lat());
            $('#long').text(place.geometry.location.lng());

            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                  origins: [new google.maps.LatLng(
                      place.geometry.location.lat(),
                      place.geometry.location.lng())],
                  destinations: ['Raleigh, NC'],
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
                },
                function(response, status) {
                    if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status == 'ZERO_RESULTS')
                        $('#distance').text('No dice!');
                    else
                        $('#distance').text(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
                });
        });
});
```

Here is the fiddle i have been working on;
http://jsfiddle.net/272tx3qy/8/
I am trying to limit input box results to Raleigh, NC only(Only streets and addresses in Raleigh, NC)

Is it something possible to achieve using Google Maps?

Thanks in advance for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Autocomplete options to use geocode as the type, which will restrict the results that are returned to addresses, Try this:

```
function initialize() {
 var input = document.getElementById( 'searchTextField' );
 var options = {
    bounds: yourBounds,
    types: ['geocode']
 };
 autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options );
}
```